# WhatsApp chat export not working

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, telegram

Exporting WhatsApp chat doesn't work from Android (WhatsApp v2.21.1.16, Android 11).

When exporting a chat, it exports only partially (circa 20MB+/- 3MB). Exporting the same chat from an iPhone works fine.

Any ideas?

Can't wait to be rid of WhatsApp. Telegram all the way.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, WhatsApp has a limitation on how many messages you can export.

> When exporting with media, you can send up to 10,000 latest messages. Without media, you can send 40,000 messages. These constraints are due to maximum email sizes.  https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/how-to-save-your-chat-history/?lang=en

You might be successful in transferring your chat to an iDevice or accessing the database of the backup on your computer.